# RubyMine row upper the navigation bar

Tags: ruby, interface, ide, rubymine

How can I hide the row with project name between main menu and navigation bar? See [this](https://ibb.co/KDM0rH5).

Comment: View --> Toolbar ?

Comment: Do you use any 3rd party theme plugin? If so then how does it go without it?